# I am trying to extract a text from a span tag within a span tag inside a text but having issues

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am sure this has been answered already and I have asked AI and have looked at answers I am having issues trying to extract the text's "Click & Collect - Luxury Goods" and "Auckland Airport". I am new to programming and just finished ATBS. Did some googling and got a code to work but it just extracts "Job Title" in span.

Code:

```
for jobs in testing:
    job_names = jobs.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'span')
    print(job_names.text)
```

[HTML code of website from which I am trying to extract the information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXbf.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXbf.jpg): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXbf.jpg)

*Have amended the image. Can't use BS4 and JS dynamically changes the website apparently so left with using Selenuim which I want to anyways. However, unable to extract the div components after the span elements. Any ideas?

*The answer is:

```
job_elements = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.g08t882.g08t884.g08t887.aoyz142.d3eu8q0.d3eu8qf._1igc8rlh')
    links = []
    for job_element in job_elements:
        link = job_element.get_attribute("href")
            links.append(link)
```

You have to go through trial and error to find the correct CSS Selector and it's class. E.g., it may be in the 'a' class field, so you will use something like a.g08t882.g08t884.g08t887.aoyz142.d3eu8q0.d3eu8qf._1igc8rlh or if it's in the href field. You would use href.g08t882.g08t884.g08t887.aoyz142.d3eu8q0.d3eu8qf._1igc8rlh for example. This depends on what you are trying to get from the HTML text using the CSS selector.

Comment: What data are you trying to get? If it is a different element than the image provided, please paste or link to the code here

Comment: Please add the html as text, not as a picture.

Comment: I have just amended the picture sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get_attribute()` method to get text from the span element.

```py
for jobs in testing:
    job_names = jobs.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'span')
    print(job_names.get_attribute('textContent').strip())
```

Comment: You are correct. I found the solution and used:                                                         job_elements = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.g08t882.g08t884.g08t887.aoyz142.d3eu8q0.d3eu8qf._1igc8rlh')
    links = []
    for job_element in job_elements:
        link = job_element.get_attribute("href")
            links.append(link)